I want to write v(x+)/v(vin) instead of v(x+). how will I do?


I want to write v(x+)/v(vin) instead of v(x+). how will I do?

Given that your circuit shows Vin as grounded this seems a bit pointless.

It would be nice if you could edit your question to add a higher resolution screenshot of your schematic. While it is just barely readable enough to answer your question, it's quite hard to make out the node labels. Also: I don't believe this question should be closed. While it has some quality issues, it is very much answerable in a definitive and clear way.

To expand a bit on Andy Aka's comment: LTspice coalesces all connected signals into a single node. This means that V(VIN) does not exist in your simulation as it has been merged into GND. If you try to plot it, you will get an error saying that the expression is invalid ("unknown voltage requested").
The issue lies here on the left side of your schematic:

Assuming that you fix this, you can right-click on the name of the variable in the plot (in this case V(X+)) and enter a new expression to plot in the dialog that pops up.

You can also right-click anywhere on the graph and select "Add traces", which is also available under the keyboard shortcut "A".


As you said, I got an unknown voltage error. I still haven't found the reason.

@BatuhanYılmaz To say it in other words: There is no "VIN" because you set "VIN=GND" in your circuit. If you connect two named signals together, only one will "survive", and in this case that's GND. You probably wanted to insert a signal source that gives you an actual VIN signal instead of just connecting it directly to GND. (GND is the little triangular "down-arrow" symbol.)
